Enforcing Java's built in HTTP client to reuse connection
I'm implementing my own HTTP server in Java using ServerSocket. I want to start implementing pipelining so I wrote a test that I'm expecting to fail first.
void sendMultipleRequestsOnSameConnection() throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("LOREM"))
            .uri(new URI("http://127.0.0.1/wait2"))
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

        HttpRequest httpRequest2 = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("LOREM"))
            .uri(new URI("http://127.0.0.1/wait"))
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> future1 = httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        Thread.sleep(500);
        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> future2 = httpClient.sendAsync(httpRequest2, BodyHandlers.ofString());

My server logs each time it accepts a new connection. After running this test I noticed that the server is accepting 2 connections, I was expecting 1 connection only since I have another test that does something similar and it's opening only 1 connection with the server.
This is the test that is working as expected:
    @Test
    void sendMultipleRequestsOnSameConnection() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString("LOREM"))
            .uri(new URI("http://127.0.0.1/"))
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

        String responseBody1 = httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();
        String responseBody2 = httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString()).body();

        Assertions.assertEquals("HELLO WORLD", responseBody1);
        Assertions.assertEquals("HELLO WORLD", responseBody2);
    }

Any idea why this is happening? Is there a way I can enforce the HTTP client to reuse the same connection from the first request? If not then is there any external Java HTTP client that allows this or will I need to use Socket directly to ensure only 1 connection gets opened?
this is a link to the repository: https://github.com/dev-rifaii/http-from-scratch/tree/pipelining

Is the first sendAsync actually complete after 500 milliseconds?  Obviously one cannot send two simultaneous requests on a single connection.

@VGR no it's not, the request is going to an endpoint that sleeps for 2 seconds. The second request goes to an endpoint that sleeps for 1 second. The point of the test is to make sure the responses are coming back in the correct order regardless of how long each of them take.

I’m not sure if this is what you want, but you can force an HttpClient to send its requests one at a time by specifying a single threaded executor.  For example:  httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).build();

After many failed attempts, I ended up going with Apache HTTP client. Here's how the test looks like now: https://github.com/dev-rifaii/http-from-scratch/blob/master/src/itest/java/dev/rifaiii/http/PipeliningITest.java#L71
